# plot negative and positive values in same Y-axis in coreplot ios

Tags: ios, core-plot

This is the I am creating scatterplot:

```
  -(void)createScatterPlotsWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier color:(CPTColor *)color forGraph:(CPTGraph *)graph forXYPlotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)plotSpace{


CPTScatterPlot *scatterPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
scatterPlot.dataSource = self;
scatterPlot.identifier = identifier;

//Plot a graph with in the plotspace
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:scatterPlot, nil]];

plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(30)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(-50) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(250)];

CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [[self getCoreplotSpace].xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(-1)];
[self getCoreplotSpace].xRange = xRange;

CPTMutableLineStyle *scatterLineStyle = [scatterPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
scatterLineStyle.lineWidth = 1;
scatterLineStyle.lineColor = color;
scatterPlot.dataLineStyle = scatterLineStyle;

CPTMutableLineStyle *scatterSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
scatterSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = color;

CPTPlotSymbol *scatterSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
scatterSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:color];
scatterSymbol.lineStyle = scatterSymbolLineStyle;
scatterSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
scatterPlot.plotSymbol = scatterSymbol;

[graph addPlot:scatterPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

}
```

Configuring the Y-axis like this:

```
  NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:4];
NSMutableSet *yLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:4];
NSArray *yAxisLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-50", @"33", @"117", @"200", nil];
NSArray *customTickLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:-50], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:33], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:117], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:200],nil];

for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < [yAxisLabels count]; i++ ) {

    NSLog(@"%@",[yAxisLabels objectAtIndex:i]);
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[yAxisLabels objectAtIndex:i]]  textStyle:axisTextStyle];
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInteger([[customTickLocations objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]);

    label.offset = y.majorTickLength;
    if (label) {
        [yLabels addObject:label];
        [yLocations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[customTickLocations objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]]];
    }
    label = nil;
}
y.axisLabels = yLabels;
y.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:customTickLocations];
```

Could you please find the screenshot.
I have following issues.

1. I am able to set the y axis but the graph is taking -50 as 0.
2. In screenshot, y axis is not aligned properly.
3. only axis are in bold color. how can I change that to normal.

could you please help me on these issues.

Thanks ...

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString` has an `integerValue` method that will parse the string contents into an `NSInteger`. Use the `doubleValue` method for floating point values. For more complex number parsing tasks, use `NSScanner`.

For example,

```
label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInteger(yAxisLabels[i].integerValue);
```

and

```
[yLocations addObject:@(yAxisLabels[i].integerValue)];
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. But I am able display the axis like -50,33,117,200. But I am unable to plot the graph. Because on Y-axis, label values are taking 0,1,2,3,4. But values are coming like 50, 60, 40,etc. Hoe can I plot the graph

Comment: Thanks Eric. Please check the updated answer.Y-axis labels are not coming on the graph. please dont mind help me on this.

Comment: PLease help me Eric. I am trying this from morning onwards but no luck.

Comment: The `yRange` extends between 0 and 4 while the ticks and labels are between -50 and 200. Change the `yRange` to location -50 and length 250 (200 -(-50)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try I will let u know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Eric. Please check updated question. I have tried by setting the range as you said but no luck for me. Please check and help me

Comment: What is the `xRange`? The y-axis is set to cross the x-axis at x = 1 (the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal `).

Comment: Thanks Eric. I put visual range for Y-axis. Then It came. But -50 is not displaying. But the graph is taking '0' by default.

Comment: There have been so many edits to the question that I'm not sure what you're asking any more. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Please check the updated question and also screenshot. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: #1: Show the rest of the y-axis setup so we can see what's going on. #2: The y-axis looks fine with what you've shown so far. #3: Change the line style for the axis lines and/or tick marks. You have full control over the color, width, and many other properties of the lines.

Comment: Thanks Eric. #1: y axis contains only 4 lines -50,33,117,200.#2. Y axis is not aligned means it is not separated by equal spaces like x axis.

Comment: Both places you are converting the "-50" location, you're casting it to an unsigned number first. Don't do that. `CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(-50)` -> `CPTDecimalFromInteger(-50)` and `[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:-50]` -> `@-50`

Comment: Sorry Eric. i am little bit confused. Could you please explain in details. please dont mind

Comment: You have to treat -50 as a *signed* integer. Casting it to unsigned in the axis range and tick location are causing the value to change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60011/discussion-between-user3774439-and-eric-skroch).

Comment: Thanks alot Eric. Now I understand what you said. I set that  CPTDecimalFromInteger in range, that solves me two issues #1.Casting and #2. alignment of y-axis. Thanks once again.